# How do I render two different partials with the same name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have

```
render @users
```

in my users view. It renders the `@users` in a nicely formatted way that I specified in `_user.html.erb`. I am now trying to do this:

```
render @attendees
```

which is a hash of users. I am trying to render this in my events view (a different view). The problem is that I want to `render @attendees` differently than `@users` but it always seems to use the `_user.html.erb` to render. How do I specify a different rendering?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, you can't use the convenience of `render @attendees` to render a different partial than `_user` since `@attendees` are actually `User` objects. Rails uses the class to figure out what partial to render when using this condensed format.

What you can do is `render :partial => 'users/attendees', :collection => @attendees`, assuming you have a partial `users/_attendees.html.erb`. If you don't want to throw that around everywhere, wrap it in a helper.